# sum of infinte series with exponential and factorial terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Want to sum the following series:
$$
\sum_{t=1}^\infty e^{-tk} \frac{(tk)^t}{t!}
$$
where $k$ is an integer $>0$.

Comment: use taylor series to calculate estimated sum of the series

Comment: There is probably no closed form for the sum (when it converges).  What do you **really** need?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to estimate:

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty e^{-tk} \frac{(tk)^t}{t!}$$

Taylor Series **rough** estimation

$$ f(k) = \sum_{t=1}^\infty e^{-tk} \frac{(tk)^t}{t!}= k + e^{-2k}\frac{2k}{2!} +e^{-3k} \frac{3k^3}{3!}+ e^{-4k} \frac{4k^4}{4!} + e^{-5k} \frac{5k^5}{5!}+ e^{-6k} \frac{6k^6}{6!}$$

if integer $$K > 0$$

Comment: Source - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_as_definitions